# Downloaded size is smaller than real size

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, google-chrome

I have deployed a website in my server by Nginx and CloudFlare. When I ssh the server and do `ls -l` over `editor.main.js` and `editor.main.js.map`, it shows that their size is `1778867` and `6379687` respectively.

However, when I check them in Google Chrome with `Disable cache`, I see their size is respectively `373K` and `1.4M`, which are smaller than real size. But the files look identical.

Does anyone know what's happening?

[image]

https://www.funfun.io/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js

https://www.funfun.io/monaco-editor/min-maps/vs/editor/editor.main.js.map

Comment: I guess it’s gzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome is showing data downloaded, and has negotiated gzip with the web server.

Request header:

```
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Response header:

```
content-encoding: gzip
```

I downloaded your [file](http://editor.main.js) then gzip'd it manually. Original size 1778867, gzip'd size 407149 bytes at -9 compression level (393KiB) or 409186 bytes at default.

Not sure how your web server got it down to 373KB, maybe smarter compression software. [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180509_93_bca7a562c3f0b3ed66c5858c7eaef900/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1) reports it as 393KB as well.

Comment: It might be using brotli compression instead of gzip or deflate, that can typically get slightly better ratios.

Comment: I did wonder that, but the response header says gzip rather than "br".

Comment: It might be using settings that don't match any of the gzip compression levels.  There are actually multiple tunables for the DEFLATE algorithm, the levels just give quick presets.

Comment: Yep, that's the kind of thing I meant by smarter compression software.